# Deleting shapefile element using Fiona?

Tags: python, shapefile, geoprocessing, geometry, fiona

I have downloaded a shapefile (.shp) that I'd like to read in using fiona.open and delete records. The reason I'd like to delete records is that some records have "None" geometries.

So I want to delete a record if it doesn't have a geometry: {'geometry': None, 'type': 'Feature', 'id':  etc etc etc}

Here's my code:

```
import fiona
with fiona.open('data/ssc_2016_aust_shape/SSC_2016_AUST.shp') as file:
    for p in file: # for every record - note that p is a dictionary 
        if p["geometry"] is None: # if p doesn't have a geometry
            del p # then delete the entire record in the shape file
```

I'd like for the original shapefile (.shp) to be overwritten (this is important).

You can download the shapefile here: http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.003July%202016?OpenDocument

The file on the ABS website is called "State Suburbs ASGS Ed 2016 Digital Boundaries in ESRI Shapefile Format" in the form of a ZIP file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, directly.  See the [`fiona` user manual](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html):

> **1.6   Writing Vector Data**
>
> A vector file can be opened for writing in mode 'a' (append) or mode 'w' (write).
>
> > *Note:*
> >
> > *The in situ “update” mode of OGR is quite format dependent and is therefore not supported by Fiona.*
>
> ...

You could copy the valid records to a temporary dataset (see [Writing New Files)](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html#writing-new-files) and then copy it over the original, or you could just operate on the valid records only (see filtering topic - [Slicing and masking iterators](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html#slicing-and-masking-iterators)).

For example (based on the [`fiona` user manual](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html)):

```
#Note completely untested...

with fiona.open(inshp) as source, fiona.open(outshp, 'w',
                                             driver=source.driver,
                                             crs=source.crs,
                                             schema=source.schema) as dest:
    for feat in source:
        if feat["geometry"] is not None:
            dest.write(feat)
```

Comment: Luke, I'd really appreciate your help: How do I move the elements of one shape file into the other? is this an easy task?

Comment: Basically, i want to create a new shape file. then use the old shape file to move records across. in particular, i only want records with a non-null geometry (or maybe even records with a Polygon geometry)

Answer (score 1):

According to the accepted answer, you cannot do what you want using fiona.

I would advise you to use [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) instead.

You can [open the Shapefile file](https://geopandas.org/io.html) and [remove a row by a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49291779/8447990).

PS: I know this question was asked 3 years ago, but I'm answering it in order to help others.